# Variable name completion in ksh

Tags: ksh, autocomplete, mksh

While I am in bash , I am able to do a tab complete with environment variable names, but with ksh I am not able to do so. How can I get it done with KSH?
I am using mksh with cygwin.

Comment: The MirBSD (and PD on which it's based) implementation of `ksh` doesn't support it. Use the `zsh` or AT&T implementation instead.

Comment: Since you have Cygwin, why not use bash (which IIRC is installed by default) or install zsh?

Comment: My problem is , I am put into a learning window where I am asked to get trained in KSH with the limited resources that I have, in this case cygwin :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mksh` author here (again) ☻

Tab completion in `mksh` is deliberately deterministic: the first word on the line (or after certain characters like `)` and `;`) is completed as a command by default, all other words are completed as filenames by default.

However, once you wrote a variable name, e.g. `echo $PWD_` (where `_` is your cursor) and press Tab, the variable will (since a couple of versions) be expanded inline (e.g. to `echo /_` if you’re in the root directory).

Feel free to visit mksh’s IRC channel (pointed out at the end of its manpage) in addition… there is no [mksh](/questions/tagged/mksh) tag here yet, so I’m only looking in here occasionally.